# Write into the same CSV file multiple times

Tags: java, performance, csv, io, spring

I implemented an `OutputWriterService.class` to write content in the same file multiple times.

The `writeToCsvFile` method is called round about 50.000 times and includes a list of descrptions which also needs to iterate and write to the file.

Is it a good way to instantiate a new `Filewriter`, `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` for every call?

```
public void writeToCsvFile(List<CustomTypeDescription> descriptions){
        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
        {
            for(CustomTypeDescription description : descriptions){
                out.println(description.toString());
            }

            //here the fw.flush()?

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createOutputFile() throws IOException {
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME), "utf-8"))) {
        }
    }
```

---

**Update:**

Is it necessary to flush `File`-, `Buffered`- and `Print`writer one by one or just the `FileWriter`. I would do it after the loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27048070/648075 ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB the answer mentioned to flush the FileWriter. Is it necessary to flush File, Buffered and Printwriter one by one or just the FileWriter. I would do it after the loop?

Comment: I don't know, I'm a C# guy, haven't done Java in ages. Just quickly googled it because I found the absence of a call to Flush odd.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Ok ;). Thanks anyway. It was a good hint.

Comment: Refer : [flushing buffer writer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908168/when-to-flush-a-bufferedwriter)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the creation of the `*Writers` on each call of `writeToCsvFile()` method, one of solutions would be as follows.

Change `OutputWriterService` class to implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface. This will allow to put its instances into a `try-with-resources` block. The `Writers` created inside the original method will become constants in the changed class and they will be closed inside the `close()` method when the routine exits from the block (normally or with an exception):

```
public class OutputWriterService implements AutoCloseable {

  private static final String FILE_NAME = "FILE";

  private final FileWriter fw;
  private final BufferedWriter bw;
  private final PrintWriter out;


  public OutputWriterService() throws IOException {
    this.fw = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, true);
    this.bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    this.out = new PrintWriter(bw);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    this.fw.close();
    this.bw.close();
    this.out.close();
  }

  public void writeToCsvFile(List<CustomTypeDescription> descriptions){
    // ...
  }

}
```

`writeToCsvFile()` method becomes shorter:

```
public void writeToCsvFile(List<CustomTypeDescription> descriptions){
  try {
    for(CustomTypeDescription description : descriptions){
      out.println(description.toString());
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

By the way, the code of the original `createOutputFile()` method looks *very* suspicious. A cleaner way would be to use

```
Files.createFile(Paths.get(FILE_NAME));
```

The instance of the `BufferedWriter` can also be created differently:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), 
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                        StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

This makes the `FileWriter` instance unnecessary.

Now, the user of your `OutputWriterService` class should proceed as follows:

```
try (OutputWriterService service = new OutputWriterService()) {

  // May be called as many times as desired, depending on the algorithm
  // The same instances of the writers will be reused. 
  service.writeToCsvFile(descriptions);

} // + process the exception or rethrow it
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to flush, because any buffered data not already written will be flushed at the end of the `try` block.  This is because a `close()` operation automatically flushes remaining data, and you guarantee that everything will be closed at the end of the `try` block by declaring your closable resources between the parentheses at the top of the `try` block.